# Ararat synapse TTCPBlockSocket creating and connecting in one thread, using in another thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety

In one of our products we use [Ararat Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/)

I have one thread that creates a `TTCPBlockSocket` object and connects to the server:

```pascal
FReaderSocket := TTCPBlockSocket.Create;
FReaderSocket.CloseSocket;
FReaderSocket.Connect(FReaderAddress, IntToStr(FReaderPort));
```

After that the worker thread is created and `FReaderSocket` is passed to it via constructor. This worker thread then uses it to communicate with the server.

Only worker thread uses the `FReaderSocket`.

Is it safe to use the `TTCPBlockSocket` in a worker thread if it was created and connection was made in another thread?

Comment: Is it thread safe... very likely... but without having access to library source code it is impossible to be 100% sure. There are other questions though... first why are you calling CloseSocket immediately after constructing socket. It is not yet connected to anything. Second question, if you are not sure whether constructing and connecting in one thread and further usage in another is thread safe, why don't you move all that in background thread?

Comment: The [library source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/synalist/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/) also supports OpenSSL 1.1 (in contrast to [public releases](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download)).

Comment: @Dalija Prasnink, thank you for your insights. Its a legacy code, so I'm not sure why the CloseSocket was used before connecting. Seems strange and unnescesary. For why I don't move the creation of the socket into the thread - I can, but in order ro change I need/want to know it is bad the way it is now. I don't want fixing what is not broken (as the code was written by other programmer).

Comment: @AmigoJack thank you for link. Do you think it can be related to thread safety?